# Create and write text to a file in java

Tags: java

I write this code to output text file but it doesn't produce any file after running it.

```
String text1="hello word";

try {
    File file = new File("f0f0f0f.txt");
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    fileWriter.write(text1);
    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking in the correct path?

Comment: I search the whole drives for f0f0f0f.txt

Answer (score 3):

If that code runs without an error, it *will* produce a file ... unless `File` or `FileWriter` are not the standard `java.io` classes.

But the file that you are creating will be in the JVM's true "current directory" ... which may not be where you are looking for it.

---

Your code could be simplified (see @Vaibhav Mule's answer) but that is not the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String text1 = "hello word";
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("f0f0f0f.txt");

try {
        fileWriter.write(text1);

        fileWriter.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```